# NextJS Router browser back button not working properly

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm currently working on a website with nextjs but when I click on the previous page button of my browser the dom is not updating. The url change but the content of the page remain the same.

Did someone already deal with this issue ? Thank's everyone.

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to find a solution?. it's weird the url change doesn't trigger the re-render.

Comment: same issue here, any solution?